# Old functions not removed from function app

Tags: azure-functions

On initial publish from Visual Studio a function app had several functions and they all worked ok. I then removed all of them except one, republished the function app and the non-existent functions are still listed in the portal.

There is no way to remove the non-existent functions from the portal. They are all still listed and it's not possible to delete them:

> Use your local development environment to edit this Function App. This
> Function App was created in a local environment and cannot be edited
> in the Azure portal.

They don't exist in the local development environment or in `function.json`.

Is there any way to force them to delete from the portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's a VisualStudio thing. For VisualStudio Mac this worked for me:

```
Properties/PublishProfiles/TestFunctionApp - Web Deploy.pubxml
```

and adding:

```
<SkipExtraFilesOnServer>False</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
```

It only works if I choose that publish profile from the list otherwise using Publish to Azure overwrites the publish profile and sets `SkipExtraFilesOnServer` back to `True` and non-existent functions aren't deleted.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I test it in my side. After republish the function app(with only one function) to azure, azure portal still show the non-existent functions.

But if we wait a few minutes and refresh the page, it will just show one function on azure portal. Please have a try again.

Comment: thanks for that but the portal has been showing the non-existent functions for weeks

Comment: Hi @codebrane Could you please provide a screenshot of your portal and a screenshot of "Solution Explorer" in your visual studio ?

Comment: If you have a class library project it should remove once you will upload new dll's. Best you can delete Azure function and recreate and publish.